# I learnt that anterior axillary folds are formed by pec maj but I can palpate and feel a hard tendon like structure

Tags: anatomy

What is that hard tube like structure that I can feel in anterior axillary folds? I think it can’t be pec major because it’s tendon is bilaminar not like a tube? Is it suspension ligament formed by clavicpectoral fascia in anterioinferior axillary part? I am just curious

Comment: Flex various muscles in your arm while feeling the structure. The action which causes the tension to increase should give you the answer. *Please note that we ask that you show evidence of searching for an answer when you ask a question.* You've asked a number of them without doing so, and I even answered an early one. Please follow the site's requirements. It will get you the answers you want.